# Replace the commas which are not inside parenthesis,quotes

Tags: java, regex

For the given input string
 *`abc,[def,ghi,ijk],lm,(no,pq,rs),[tu,vw,xy],zs,"as,as,fr"`*
output should be

```
abc [def,ghi,ijk] lm (no,pq,rs) [tu,vw,xy] zs "as,as,fr"
```

I tried this 
*`str.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)|(,)", " ");`*
 
say my string is str, it will replace commas which are not inside ( ) but output will not have content inside ( )

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: i replaced with space here

Comment: Comma should not be replaced inside ( ),{ },[ ]," ",' '

Answer (score 3):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched comma with a space.

```
,(?=(?:"[^\["(){}\]]*"|\([^\["{}()\]]*\)|\[[^\["{}()\]]*\]|\{[^\["(){}\]]*}|[^"\[{}()\]])*$)
```

OR

```
,(?=(?:"[^"]*"|\([^()]*\)|\[[^\[\]]*\]|\{[^{}]*}|[^"\[{}()\]])*$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/17)

```
String s = "\"f,g\",abc,[def,ghi,ijk],lm,(no,pq,rs),[tu,vw,xy],zs,\"as,as,fr\",foo,{bar,buz}";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(",(?=(?:\"[^\\[\"(){}\\]]*\"|\\([^\\[\"{}()\\]]*\\)|\\[[^\\[\"{}()\\]]*\\]|\\{[^\\[\"(){}\\]]*}|[^\"\\[{}()\\]])*$)", " "));
```

**Output:**

```
"f,g" abc [def,ghi,ijk] lm (no,pq,rs) [tu,vw,xy] zs "as,as,fr" foo {bar,buz}
```

**Explanation:**

- `,` Matches all the commas
- `,(?=` ONly if it's followed by,
- `"[^\["(){}\]]*"` A double quotes block like `"foo,bar"`
- `|` OR
- `\([^\["{}()\]]*\)` paranthesis block like `(foo,bar)`
- `|` OR
- `\[[^\["{}()\]]*\]` a square bracket block like  `[foo,bar]`
- `|` OR
- `\{[^\["(){}\]]*}` A curly brace block like `{foo,bar}`
- `|` OR
- `[^"\[{}()\]]` Any character but not of `"` or `(` or `)` or `{` or `[` or `]` or `}`.
- zero or more times. This applies to the whole, that is like `(foo,bar)` may be repeated zero or more times.
- `$` Followed by an end of the line anchor.

Comment: Thankyou so much @Avinash Raj for the detailed explanation, this is working like gangbusters,i added support for single quote also

Comment: yep, it's not necessary for this case.. Yep, you could add any number of blocks in the above regex.

Comment: yep, it's called non-capturing group. `()` called capturing group which captures those character which are matched by the pattern present inside that group. Then later we could refer those captured characters through back referencing. But a non-capturing group does the same as capturing but it won't capture any characters. If we want to do matching only then non-capt group would be enough. see https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/19 and https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/20

Comment: yep , we are already matched the blocks but `[^"[{}()]]` at the last helps to match all the characters which are present outside the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simpler regex for this. Match this regex:

```
(\[[^]]*\]|\([^)]*\)|"[^"]*"),?|,
```

And replace by:

```
"$1 "
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW4tU0/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
,(?![^\[({]*[\])}])(?![^"']*["'](?:[^"']*["'][^"']*["'])*[^"']*$)
```

This should work fine for you.The lookahead will make sure `,` is not between parenthesis or quotes.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/8

For java `escape \ again.make it \\`

Or if you can live with some extra spaces. try

```
(['"(\[{].*?['")}\]])|,
```

Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/7

Comment: Thankyou so much @vks , this is working great, but it is replacing comma if it is inside single quote and flower braces like if input is 'ad,cd,ef',ad,{fg,ef,rg} output is 'ac cd ef' ad {fg ef rg}

Comment: @user3607869 can you post the example where it is failing?

Comment: abc,[def,ghi,ijk],lm,{no,pq,rs},[tu,vw,xy],zs,"as,as,fr,ghhh",'gf,ef,rd'  in this comma inside ' ' and flower braces are also replaced with space

Answer (score 0):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
    String s = "abc,[def,ghi,ijk],lm,(no,pq,rs),[tu,vw,xy],zs,\"as,as,fr\",xyz,pqr";
    String[] arr = s.split("(,(?![\\w,]+[\\]\\)\"]))|((?<=[\\]\"\\)]),)");
    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
abc
[def,ghi,ijk]
lm
(no,pq,rs)
[tu,vw,xy]
zs
"as,as,fr"
xyz
pqr
```

PS : The below code will work for `single quotes and flower braces` as well

```
String[] arr = s.split("(,(?![\\w,]+[^,\\w]))|((?<=[^,\\w]),)");
```